# What are the steam trading cards you can get for the Steam summer sale 2015?

Tags: steam

I can't get into the steam game thing that they have that gives you card drops for the Steam summer badge, so I was wondering if anyone has the names of the cards so I can just buy/trade for them.

Comment: you should look for the monster cards

Answer (score 5):

You can see the all cards when you log into your account, hover over your name in the menu and then choose "Badges".

[image]

There you can look at all Monster Summer Sale cards by clicking on the box of Monster Summer Sale.

[image]

Here is the overview

[image]

The names of the cards are:

- Bob
- Dominic
- Blitzkrieg
- Cerulean Carmouth
- Sigmond
- Crusta-Sean
- Dansky
- Dire Frog
- Z-Lo
- Gold Helm